# I am trying to use cursor object IN parameter from Node JS to Oracle DB getting Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

Can someone please advise since I am getting a Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2 from using below code. I am trying to send a in parameter cursor object to oracle db. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
var sqlQuery = "BEGIN pck_notification.prc_insert_notification(:pi_data,:po_batch_id,:po_error,:po_error_message);"
        + "END;";
    var dbConn = null;
    try {
        dbConn = await 

dbModel.getDbConnectionWithEncryption(tenantCode);

        var notification_obj = {};
        notification_obj.template_id = "155";
        notification_obj.tc_txn_iid = "1343";
        notification_obj.stmt_points_flushed_month = "15";
        notification_obj.partner_name = "Test";
        notification_obj.voucher_value = "FB";
        notification_obj.batch_id = "";
        notification_obj.cif_id = "";
        notification_obj.txn_date = "";
        notification_obj.categories = "";


        var pi_data = [];
        pi_data.push(notification_obj);
        logger.info("", "Notification procedure request data is " + JSON.stringify(pi_data));
        var bindvars = {
            pi_data: { val: pi_data, type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN },
            po_batch_id: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
            po_error: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
            po_error_message: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT }
        }

        var outdata = await dbConn.execute(
            sqlQuery,
            bindvars).catch(err => {
                logger.error('', 'Error in DB procedure call ' + err.stack);
                DBUtil.releaseConnection(dbConn);
                return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
            });
        var responseData = {
            po_batch_id: outdata.outBinds.po_batch_id,
            po_error: outdata.outBinds.po_error,
            po_error_message: outdata.outBinds.po_error_message,
        };
```

Comment: Please update your question with the PL/SQL procedure definition showing the parameter types.  Side tips: using backticks for SQL strings lets you have multi-line statements without needing to use `+`.  Passing a cursor `IN` may lose rows until the driver allows "prefetching" to be turned off. Make sure `po_error_message` is given a `maxSize` if the expected length is longer than node-oracledb's default size. Do you really need to use promises? You are already using async/await which does the same but is clearer.

Comment: KIRUBA SHANKAR, do you still need help with this or were you able to solve it?

Comment: I am able to solve this. Thanks for your suggestions.